# Is there a way to use Lists as values in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm dealing with the famous Kaggle challenge "House prices".
I want to train my Dataset with sklearn.linear_model LinearRegression

After reading the following article:
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/representation/feature-engineering

I wrote a function converting all String values in my train DataFrame into Lists. 
For example an original feature values might look like this [Ex, Gd, Ta, Po] and after the conversion it will look like this: [1,0,0,0] [0,1,0,0] [0,0,1,0] [0,0,0,1].

When I try to train my data I get the following Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/HousePrices/main.py", line 27, in
>   
>       linereg.fit(train_df, target)   File "C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\HousePrices\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py",
>   line 458, in fit
>       y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)   File "C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\HousePrices\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 756, in check_X_y
>       estimator=estimator)   File "C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\HousePrices\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 567, in check_array
>       array = array.astype(np.float64) ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

This only happens when I convert some columns as I explained.

Is there any way to train a Linear-Regression model with vectors as values?

This is my conversion function:

```
def feature_to_boolean_vector(df, feature_name, new_name):
    vectors_list = [] #each tuple will represent an option
    feature_options = df[feature_name].unique()
    feature_options_length = len(feature_options)

    # creating a list the size of feature_options_length, all 0's
    list_to_be_vector = [0 for i in range(feature_options_length)]

    for i in range(feature_options_length):
        list_to_be_vector[i] = 1 # inserting 1 representing option number i
        vectors_list.append(list_to_be_vector.copy())
        list_to_be_vector[i] = 0

    mapping = dict(zip(feature_options, vectors_list)) # dict from values to vectors
    df[new_name] = df[feature_name].map(mapping)
    df.drop([feature_name], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

And this is my train attempt (after pre-processing):

```
linereg = LinearRegression()
linereg.fit(train_df, target)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) is normally used for that. Another option is to work your data as [categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearRegression` does not support list as a feature. I saw you're using one-hot, and you can use each dimension as a column of features. By contrast, you can use the simpler method `pd.get_dummies` in pandas.

```
print(df['feature'])
0    Ex
1    Gd
2    Ta
3    Po
Name: feature, dtype: object

df = pd.get_dummies(df['feature'])
print(df)
   Ex  Gd  Po  Ta
0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0
2   0   0   0   1
3   0   0   1   0
```